# call xp_cmdshell with xml parameter

Tags: xml, xp-cmdshell

It was created console application that has two param: one is a command like "send"  and second is a xml string like `"<Messages><msg>My message</msg></Messages>"`. Console application will return something like: `"<Messages><msg>Handled message</msg></Messages>"` after execution.

The question is how to call stored procedure xp_cmdshell mentioned above console application using T-SQL. The main problem is how to send parameter with xml. For example, mentioned above console application, can be executed with this expression:

```
"c:\consoleapp.exe" send "<Messages><msg>My message</msg></Messages>"
```

This expression can be executed without problem from console, but not with xp_cmdshell.
In the case of xp_cmdshell sql server outut will return:

```
< was unexpected at this time.
```

Comment: Try double-quoting (`""`) the XML.

Comment: Thank you for response, but this didn't help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that script:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell '""D:\ConsoleTest.exe" "<Messages><msg>My message</msg></Messages>""'
```